# Gimp: fill with pattern, change pattern scale and threshold

Tags: gimp, patterns

I just filled an image with a pattern:

[image: Image filled with pattern]

Ain't there a simple way to change the scale and the threshold of the pattern so that the squares fit the edges of the house better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use layer masks instead of filling a shape or selection with a pattern directly. Keeping everything as separate layers will give you the freedom to rescale/reposition different elements.

1. Create a house shape, and use a layer mask to knock out the middle to transparency.  I used the Pen Tool to create the inside mask. (hint: Path to Selection, Add Layer Mask, from Selection)
2. Next place your image or a filled pattern layer on a layer below. Resize using the Scale Tool (Shift+T), and move into position with the Move Tool
3. Once you are happy with the positioning/rescaling. Right click the layer mask on the house image, and choose Mask to Selection, and then Select > Invert
4. Right click the pattern layer and choose Add Layer Mask, then choose the `From selection` option.

Here's a screenshot to help
[image]